# Best way to access an object to pass into a function

Tags: javascript, svg, parameters

I will make this as short and sweet as possible.

I have one .svg file that I am embedding into my HTML with the  tag.
I have embedded this file 5 times, each time giving the  a different id.
I have a function that takes 2 parameters, and is called by a second function. 
What I am trying to do is be able to select which .svg  to pass in as the parameter to be given a new color.

I know this sounds lame...this is my test file before I apply it to my real file.
Yes, I am still new at this.
What is the best way to indicate which circle I am trying to color? I have tried arrays and loops, but am clearly not executing them well.

Thank you in advance.

My HTML is this:

```
<body>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="Color Circle" onclick="GetColor()"/>        
</div><!-- end buttons div -->
<br />
<div id="inputs">
    Color:      <input type="text" id="color" /><br/>
    <!--Position:   <input type="text" id="placement" /><br/>-->
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="svg_container">
    <!--embed SVG using 'object' tag -->
    <object data="images/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="375" height="375"          id="myCircle1"></object>
    <object data="images/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="375" height="375" id="myCircle2"></object>
    <object data="images/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="375" height="375" id="myCircle3"></object>
    <object data="images/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="375" height="375" id="myCircle4"></object>
    <object data="images/circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="375" height="375" id="myCircle5"></object>  
</div><!-- end svg_container div -->
```

My JavaScript is this:

```
function GetColor(){
            var filler = document.getElementById('color').value; 
            SetColor('myCircle1', filler);                
        }
        function SetColor(circleObjId, color){
            //declare and assign variables to be able to access svg and its content
            var svg = document.getElementById('myCircle3').contentDocument;                
            var circle = svg.getElementById('svgCircle');
            //the circle variable is now equivalent to circle.svg img being referenced
            //now that we have the circle, we want to color it
            circle.style.fill = color;
        }
```

Comment: If you could put up a working sample at plunker or jsfiddle, that would help. What result are you getting from the code you posted above?

Comment: Thanks @SMcCrohan McCrohan. It's all taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For whatever reason I was using a literal where I should have been using the parameter name. So instead of var svg = document.getElementById('myCircle3'.contentDocument; it should have been var svg = document.getElementById(circleObjId).contentDocument;